# ec2 hosted lamp site not visible from browser

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, ipv4

I have setup an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 16 server for the first time.

With the issued public IPv4 IP address I have ssh'ed into the server and installed a lamp stack.

However when I paste the IP address into my browser I get the following error:

```
Error
The requested URL could not be retrieved
Error: Access to the web site failed
Why you are seeing this:
The web filter could not display the requested site.

Possible reasons could be:
The web site denied you access, or the web filter received no reply from the site.
Internet connectivity issues might be preventing the website from sending or receiving traffic.
If this problem persists, please ask your administrator to:
Check access to the specific site - the HTTP error code is 504: Gateway Timeout.
```

From what I've seen online, I should see the default apache webpage from my server at this point.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm that the server is running by running something like `curl http://localhost` from the command line of your ec2 or maybe localhost:8080?

Comment: @Mark: `curl http://localhost` returned the apache default page

Comment: I was just reading about security groups? Can that be done once an instance is setup?

Comment: Got it! It WAS the security groups.